# C# WPF binding doesn't take data from Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

In my XAML I am doing the following

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=UserData.Email, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

the `Root` element is my `Window` itself and the `UserData` Is a `get; private set;` auto property in my codebehind file, the `Email` property is get-only and is of type `string`.

the `UserData` object gets set after the user has logged in. But the binding is not taking the value from the object. I have verified that the object does indeed contain the correct data and isn't `null`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you setting the `Datacontext` of your label to your `Model`?

Comment: No, how should I do this? Since I haven't used `DataContext` before, guess ill read up a bit on what it is.

Comment: Well first you need a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`  This class would be your `Model View` part.  Then you need to instantiate an object of that class and set the DataContext to the object.  Basically so it knows where to look.  You really need to find a good tutorial.

Comment: It seems that you also misunderstood the implementation of the MVVM-pattern. What you need is a view model that contains your prepared data for the view (window). Then you're able to bind a property of that view model to a control property on the view.
For connecting both sides, you must set the window's `DataContext` either in its code behind, or directly in its XAML-code.

Comment: just get rid of the `private set` make it public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and created a hello world version for this.  Here is the xml.  This should simply change the banner when the button is clicked to the text in the text box.  I couldn't find a super simple example so I just made one.  Obviously there are way more advanced ways to do this but it should make for a simple version to build from.

```
<Window x:Class="Hello_World.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="MyLabel" Content="{Binding MyLabel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="58,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="423" FontSize="44"/>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="163,162,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163"/>
        <Button Content="Change Banner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,209,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Next is the ModelView that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.  Note that your properties must be public properties with a getter, setter and backing field.  This allows you to call the `OnPropetyChanged()` method whenever the property is set.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hello_World
{
    public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private string _myLabel;

        public string MyLabel
        {
            get { return _myLabel; }
            set
            {
                _myLabel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyLabel));
            }
        }    

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propetyName)
        {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propetyName));

        }

    }
}
```

Lastly the MainWindow.  Set the `DataContext` in the main constructor.  Note I could have set the `DataContext` of the main grid and all of its children would inherit the same `DataContext`.  This would keep you from having to set all of the components' individually.

```
namespace Hello_World
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainViewModel MyViewModel;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyViewModel = new MainViewModel();

            // Here's where I'm setting the object to look at.
            DataContext = MyViewModel;

            // Now I don't need to access the textbox directly.
            MyViewModel.MyLabel = "Hello World";    
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Note: ICommand is a more advanced topic.
            MyViewModel.MyLabel = MyTextBox.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and explanation. If I can make a small suggestion, I would use `nameof` when calling the `OnPropertyChanged` from your `MyLabel` Property