# Query ObservableCollection with Linq MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

I want to create a query with linq on my ObservableCollection but it doesn't really work how T tried it.

I have a Model `Entry` which has `{note, information, isActive}` as parameters. So I now want to simply just get all the `Entries` where isActive is true. I don't use it on my dataprovider (once the data gets loaded) because I need to load every entry into the program.

So I thought about to override the getter inside my entries ObservableCollection:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Note> _entries { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Note> entries
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Note>(from entry in this._entries
                                                  where entry.isActive == true
                                                  select entry);
        }
        set { this._entries = value; }
    }
```

But as you might guess this doesn't work.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than editing it in the get, try updating the `refinedEntries` in the `entries`' setter.  My `Linq` statement may need work but it encapsulates what I'm trying to suggest.

Essentially keep a copy of everything even the inactive records in entries and another collection to contain only the active records.  In this case I'm calling it `refinedEntries`.

```
    private ObservableCollection<Note> _entries;

    public ObservableCollection<Note> entries
    {
      get{return _entries;}
      set
      {
        _entries = value;
        RefinedEntries = new ObservableCollection(_entries.Where(e=>e.isActive).Select(e => e));
      }

     }

    public ObservableCollection<Note> refinedEntries {get;set;}
```

I would also suggest updating `refinedEntries` when `CollectionChangedEvent` fires.  In this case the only time `refinedEntries` is updated is when `entries` is set to a new instance.

When you instantiate an new collection for entries, subscribe to its `CollectionChangedEvent`.  For example if you instantiate the collection in the Model's constructor you could use the following..

```
entries = new ObservableCollection<Note>();
entries.CollectionChangedEvent += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler((sender,args) => 
{ 
   RefinedEntries = new ObservableCollection(_entries.Where(e=>e.isActive).Select(e => e));
  //Notify the UI that an update has been made.
  OnPropertyChanged("RefinedEntries");
});
```

Comment: Great thanks that works. As you mentioned the update on refinedEntries does not work. So am I correct that I have to notify the view somehow that the refinedCollection has changed inside the `entries setter` ? But how if I should ?

Comment: Yes, you should have implemented [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and set the datacontext of your wpf component.

Comment: I just wrote an example of this yesterday [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362216/c-sharp-wpf-binding-doesnt-take-data-from-property/37362721#37362721)

Comment: Yes I have, my model inherits it. Your example for the collectionchanged event doesn't seams to work. I have put it into my model constructor but still its not beeing updated :(

Comment: Are you calling `OnPropertyChanged()` method to notify the `UI`?

Comment: Yea i tried OnPropertyChanged() and OnPropertyChanged("refinedEntries") inside entries

Comment: What is changing, the collection or a property within the collection?

Comment: The whole refinedEntries collection because im creating a new one everytime right ?

Comment: You will create a new RefinedEntries every time there is an add, delete, reorder etc to check for newly active elements or remove inactive elements. But changes to individual elements' properties will carry over to the objects contained in RefinedEntries because it contains the same objects as entries.  If you want to update refinedEntries on the elements' properties you will need to use a different event.

Comment: Puh -.-" ... After rewriting your code and freshened up my mind I was able to fully understand your code (not just c&p). And now its working :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
        get
        {
            List<Notes> list = _entries.Where(e=>e.isActive).ToList(); 
            return new ObservableCollection<Note>(list) ;
        }
```

Comment: I think you are missing a select statement

Comment: @FelixCastor - i don't believe that's necessary since i'm not projecting the values (i.e Note's) into a different form

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't work. Isn't it the same as my query, just a short form?

Comment: or just without creating `list` variable `return new ObservableCollection<Note>(_entries.Where(e=>e.isActive).ToList()) ;`

Comment: @Sens4 could you provide more detail what it is not working?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean when you say 'it's not working' - is the list object from my answer empty ?

Comment: Yea the List is empty, so maybe the select is needed.

Comment: The select is not needed ( double check that _entries actually has active Note items ?)

Comment: The example on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)  says that you DON'T need a select statement.  I think auburg is correct.